# Kauffman Bracket

Tags: geometry, knot-theory

Can anyone explain or direct me to:

[image: 1]
[image: 2].

What are the x and y's? Is x cutting the loop?

And for the last picture, I don't understand how the Reidemeister moves have been applied there.

I would much appreciate the help, I've read numerous different university lecture notes not explaining this completely.

Comment: Probably the $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables in some knot polynomial. So for instance suppose $B(K_{RHS_1})=x$ and $B(K_{RHS_2})=2x$, then $B(K_{LHS})=x^2+2yx$. Remember, $B(\bullet)$ is a function which assigns to some knot diagram $\bullet$ a polynomial in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: ok, I understand that it's a function. But how does that function work? I can't figure out the rule, is it cutting the crossing or moving the crossing? how?